Unable to Call CompletableFuture with Callable
I have create a Class OrderFetcher that implements Callable interface returns a Integer from Call Method as below
public class OrderFetcher implements Callable<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        sleep(200);
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(10);
    }
}

I have also created another two classes InventoryFetcher & PaymentFetcher and these also implements callable interface
public class InventoryFetcher implements Callable<Boolean> {

    public InventoryFetcher(Integer orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    Integer orderId;

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        sleep(200);
        return this.orderId%2==0?true:false;
    }
}

public class PaymentFetcher implements Callable<String> {

    Boolean flag;

    public PaymentFetcher(Boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        sleep(200);
        return flag?"Payment Accepted":"Payment Rejected";
    }
}

I tried them with Futures and it works well where i am calling the OrderFetcher to return  a value and pass that in InventoryFethcer and the pass the output from InventoryFetcher to PaymnetFethcer class. Ones output is Input to other and so on.
But how can i acheve this in CompletableFuture? It asking for a supplier interface implementation
I tried this way
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); 

CompletableFuture<OrderFetcher> ageFut = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(OrderFetcher::new, executorService) .thenApplyAsync(InventoryFetcher::new).thenApplyAsync(PaymentFetcher::new);
    
     System.out.println(ageFut.get().call());
    
     executorService.shutdown(); 

But its giving compile time error Required type: Function <? super pkg. future. OrderFetcher, ? extends U> Provided:  OrderFetcher is not convertible to Integer

What have you tried that didn't work, and what issue did you encounter?

HI Daniu, I tried this way
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    CompletableFuture<OrderFetcher> ageFut = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(OrderFetcher::new, executorService)
            .thenApplyAsync(InventoryFetcher::new).thenApplyAsync(PaymentFetcher::new);

    System.out.println(ageFut.get().call());
    executorService.shutdown();

But its giving compile time error
Required type:
Function

Provided:

OrderFetcher is not convertible to Integer
Updated the Question

OrderFetcher::new is not a lambda returning an Integer, it is a lambda, that when executed, will return a new instance of OrderFetcher (like () -> new OrderFetcher()), but InventoryFetcher::new expects an Integer when executed, not an OrderFetcher -- the first should be something like () -> new OrderFetcher().call(). Similar problem will happen between second and third || maybe you wanted the first class to implement a Supplier, as requested by supplyAsync(), and the other two classes implement Function

I tried this way but i am unsure I am correct or not though i am getting the desired output
`CompletableFuture completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
try {
return new OrderFetcher().call();
} catch (Exception e) {
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}, executorService).thenApplyAsync(i -> {
try {
return new InventoryFetcher(i).call();
} catch (Exception e) {
        }
    })`


That looks correct (although quite hard to read in comments;  consider adding that to your question).  What output did you expect, and what output did you see instead?  (Side note: this.orderId%2==0?true:false is exactly the same as writing this.orderId%2==0.  The latter expression is already boolean.)

This answer provides solutions for the initial operation. I don’t understand why the subsequent operations are provided as Callable implementations. It doesn’t fit at all.
